# Python 3: create new process when another one finishes

Tags: python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I have an array of data to handle and handler that executing long (1-2 minutes) and takes a lot of memory for its calculations.

```
raw = ['a', 'b', 'c']

def handler():
    # do something long
```

Since handler requires a lot of memory, I want to execute it in separate subprocess and kill it after execution to release memory. Something like the following snippet:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
for r in raw:
    process = Process(target=handler, args=(r))
    process.start()
```

The problem is that such approach leads to immediate running `len(raw)` processes. And it's not good.
Also, it's not needed to interchange any kind of data between subprocesses. Just run them consequently.
Therefore it would be great to run a few processes at the same time and add a new one once existing finishes.

How could it be implemented (if it's even possible)?

Comment: Does giving sleep time between the processes help ?

Comment: why not calling `process.join()` in the loop? with that you'll wait after each process.

Comment: @ChetanVasudevan, theoretically, it does, but I guess such solution isn't elegant since execution time of handler is not constant

Answer (score 4, accepted):

to run your processes sequentially, just `join` each process within the loop:

```
from multiprocessing import Process
for r in raw:
    process = Process(target=handler, args=(r))
    process.start()
    process.join()
```

that way you're sure that only one process is running at the same time (no concurrency)

That's the simplest way. To run more than one process but limit the number of processes running at the same time, you can use a `multiprocessing.Pool` object and [apply_async](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html#multiprocessing.pool.multiprocessing.Pool)

I've built a simple example which computes the square of the argument, and simulates an heavy processing:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool
import time

def target(r):
    time.sleep(5)
    return(r*r)
raw = [1,2,3,4,5]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(3) as p:  # 3 processes at a time
        reslist = [p.apply_async(target, (r,)) for r in raw]
        for result in reslist:
            print(result.get())
```

Running this I get:

```
<5 seconds wait, time to compute the results>
1
4
9
<5 seconds wait, 3 processes max can run at the same time>
16
25
```

Comment: Could you please tell whether Pool creates each time new Process or just using existing one from previous "iteration"? I just want to be sure that after each using of `handler` a memory would be released to avoid any kind of "out-of-memory" stuff

Comment: it cannot use a previous process. This is a process pool. You can add a fake big matrix to see if the memory explodes. But anyway it cannot run out of memory because of the garbage collector.